# The default numpy.std() is only applicable for samples where n > 30. Can this be modified?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

Say I needed to find the sample standard deviation of the data set `sample A` where
`sampleA = [34.6, 40.7, 37.5, 45.8, 41.4, 44.2, 44.5, 51.8, 47.5, 45.4, 36.4, 46.2, 43.0, 43.3, 42.0] # mass (g)`. By using the `np.std()` function we obtain the result `4.309`. However, this is incorrect, as `n = 15` for `sample A`. Resulting in a necessary change in the std. dev formula due to Student's t-distribution.

The correct function would look something like this:

```
def sam_stddev(data_set):
   sum = 0
   for n in data_set:
      sum += (n - sam_mean(data_set)) ** 2
   S_x = ((1/(len(data_set) - 1) * sum)) ** 0.5
   return S_x
```

By using this function, we obtain the correct result of `4.460`. Now, obviously I can just use this defined function, but I was wondering whether there is some kind of modifier that I can use, maybe something like `np.std(sampleA, "n" = 15)` that would allow me to do this by default. Alternatively, is there another library I should be using that has this built-in? I have looked at the numpy.std() documentation at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html, but honestly, I'm inexperienced with how to actually read that.

Comment: Include the argument `ddof=1`; `np.std(sampleA, ddof=1)` returns `4.460119579861807`.  Reread the full [`docstring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html). The use of `ddof` is explained in the "Notes" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default numpy divides by `1/N`. If you want as `1/(N - 1)` then you have to set the `ddof` param to `1`

```
np_arr.std(ddof=1)
4.460119579861807
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I honesty really appreciate it.

Comment: Done! Question for if you know the answer, but in what cases would `ddof` be set to anything other than `0` or `1`?